# String Indices Must be Integers - Fetching a JSON response from a REST API in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, rest, api

I'm trying to pull data from a REST API, parsing it in JSON, and then adding the results in the CSV. The problem I'm getting is that every time I try to save the error I get is "TypeError: string indices must be integers".

```
located_at=curr_loc['located_at']
```

> TypeError: string indices must be integers

Here's the API: https://developer.keeptruckin.com/reference#get-current-vehicle-locations

The endpoint I'm accessing is /vehicle_locations

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
import json
import csv

url='https://api.keeptruckin.com/v1/vehicle_locations'
header={'x-api-key':'API KEY HERE'}
r=requests.get(url,headers=header)
result=r.json()
result = json.loads(r.text)
num_pages=result['pagination']['total']
csvheader=['Number','Date','Time','Location','Lat','Lon','Speed','Bearing','Odometer','Engine Hours']
with open('myfile1.csv', 'a+', newline='') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        ##writer.writerow(csvheader)
        for veh in result['vehicles']:
            number = veh['vehicle']['number']
            for curr_loc in veh['vehicle']['current_location']:
                located_at=curr_loc['located_at']
                date,time=located_at.split['T']
                location=curr_loc['description']
                lat=curr_loc['lat']
                lon=curr_loc['lon']
                speed=curr_loc['speed']
                bearing=curr_loc['bearing']
                engine_hours=curr_loc['engine_hours']
                odometer=curr_loc['odometer']
                if not location:
                    location = "N/A"
                writer.writerow((number, date,time, location, lat, lon,speed,bearing,odometer,engine_hours))
```

Comment: You should look at what the loop variable `curr_loc` holds. You'll find they are strings — the keys to the object `veh['vehicle']['current_location']`

Comment: @MarkMeyer I took a look and the variable curr_loc says the type is str and the value for it is lat. What should I do to resolve this?

Comment: Given that error, `curr_loc` must be a string, and indeed, you can't index strings like that.

Comment: You don't need to loop over `veh['vehicle']['current_location']`. It's already the object you want. Maybe just save it to `curr_loc = veh['vehicle']['current_location']` for convenience, then you can use `located_at=curr_loc['located_at']` etc, without the loop.

Comment: @MarkMeyer This works to an extent, but I still get an error saying:

`located_at=curr_loc['located_at']

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

I can see in the variable explorer that the variables now have the correct values in them, but I'm still getting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the API you linked, `veh['vehicle']['current_location']` is a dictionary mapping keys to string values. You don't need the `for` loop if you're accessing the keys by name. One possibility is to change your code like this:

```py
with open('myfile1.csv', 'a+', newline='') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        ##writer.writerow(csvheader)
        for veh in result['vehicles']:
            number = veh['vehicle']['number']
            curr_loc = veh['vehicle']['current_location']:
            located_at=curr_loc['located_at']
            date,time=located_at.split['T']
            location=curr_loc['description']
            lat=curr_loc['lat']
            lon=curr_loc['lon']
            speed=curr_loc['speed']
            bearing=curr_loc['bearing']
            engine_hours=curr_loc['engine_hours']
            odometer=curr_loc['odometer']
            if not location:
                location = "N/A"
            writer.writerow((number, date,time, location, lat, lon,speed,bearing,odometer,engine_hours))
```